# deshabilitar autoplay iframe

Tags: javascript, html5, prestashop1.7

hola estoy intentando hacer un delay del autoplay de un video de youtube,
he intentado estas cosas y nada...

```
document.getElementById('widget2').src+='?rel=0&amp;autoplay=0';

function autoPlayVideo() {
    document.getElementById('widget2').src+='?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1';
}

setTimeout(autoPlayVideo(), 10000);

/////

document.getElementById('widget2').allow = "accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture;";
function autoPlayVideo() {
    document.getElementById('widget2').allow+='accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture;autoplay';
  }
  setTimeout(autoPlayVideo(), 10000);
```

pero ninguna de estas dos opciones me funciona... si me podeis ayudar

gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar el API gratuita que proporciona google, de tal manera que puedas tener acceso a diversos métodos para trabajar con los vídeos (play, pause, seek, etc), así como crear y gestionar listas de vídeos y demás: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference. Ten en cuenta también que en dispositivos móviles el autoplay solo funcionará a través de una acción del usuario.